# Is it possible to store html on an smtp server , and reference it for bulk mailing as body?

Tags: c#, smtp

Using .net, I'm creating a mailing app, that uses Amazon SES. Amazon expose a standard SMTP interface, which is good, however sending mail speed is bottlenecked because every mail requires the body of the mail to be uploaded.

In this case the body is standard html, not personalized.

Is it somehow possible to upload the template to the SMTP server, and instead of traditionally formatting the body of the mail message and uploading this everytime, rather just reference the uploaded html as the body.

For example:

Current code:

```
using (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient())
                    {
                        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                        message.To.Add(item.Email);
                        message.Subject = subject;
                        message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(camp3.CampaignFromEmail);
                        message.Body = body;
                        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

                        smtp.Send(message);
                    }
```

The code I would like to write:

```
using (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient())
                    {
                        string serverGUID = smtp.uploadHTMLTemplate(id); 
                        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                        message.To.Add(item.Email);
                        message.Subject = subject;
                        message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(camp3.CampaignFromEmail);
                        message.Body = "XTemplate: " + serverGUID;
                        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

                        smtp.Send(message);
                    }
```

Would such a thing be possible?

Comment: Only if your mail server has a custom feature for it (SendGrid might).  I'm pretty sure that SMTP doesn't do anything like that.

Comment: Why do you want SMTP to do that? You can store the template in your application and just read it and assign it to the `message.Body` just like you did it in current code. As @SLaks said sendgrid has this feature, never tried it though. follow this [link](http://sendgrid.com/docs/Apps/email_templates.html)

Comment: @Nilesh - Hi there. The application I'm writing is a WPF desktop client for Amazon SES. So it runs on the users local machine. For this reason limited by the upspeed of the users DSL (etc).

Comment: @Nilesh: He wants to avoid sending the body over the network.

Comment: Ok I understand! Just another thought, would you be able to trigger some service on Amazon which queues email requests and sends them out. You can always have a template stored on the server which the  service can use.

Answer (score 0):

As per standard SMTP RFC there is no such provision unless the SMTP server exposes an interface to do so, like for example sendgrid.